# How to fix a 'list index out of range' error when using BiGSCAPE's gene cluster families?

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I'm trying to run BiGSCAPE and i keep getting this error:

What I ran: python3 BiG-SCAPE-master/bigscape.py -i *inputfile* -o *outputfile* --hybrids-off --mode auto --pfam_dir . --cutoff 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9

```
# (...)

  PKSI (93 BGCs)
   Writing annotation files
   Calculating all pairwise distances
generate_network took 0.381 seconds
   Writing output files
  Calling Gene Cluster Families
  Cutoff: 0.3

WARNING! This alignment consists of closely-related and very-long sequences.
WARNING! FastTree (or other standard maximum-likelihood tools)
may not be appropriate for aligments of very closely-related sequences
like this one, as FastTree does not account for recombination or gene conversion

/home/sofi/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/_affinity_propagation.py:250: ConvergenceWarning: Affinity propagation did noonverge, this model will not have any cluster centers.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sofi/Desktop/bigscape/BiG-SCAPE-master/bigscape.py", line 3258, in <module>
    family_data = clusterJsonBatch(BGC_classes[bgc_class], pathBase, bgc_class,
  File "/home/sofi/Desktop/bigscape/BiG-SCAPE-master/bigscape.py", line 1731, in clusterJsonBatch
    clanLabels = [familyIdx[exemplarsClans[labelsClans[i]]] for i in range(len(familyIdx))]
  File "/home/sofi/Desktop/bigscape/BiG-SCAPE-master/bigscape.py", line 1731, in <listcomp>
    clanLabels = [familyIdx[exemplarsClans[labelsClans[i]]] for i in range(len(familyIdx))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I had no problem while calling gene cluster families with NRPS, others, RiPPs or PKSothers.
I do not understand why is the list index out of range. Can anyone help me please?